# How to format a row in a table not the entire row on the sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to colour an entire row in a named range (and not outside the named range) based on the value in the first column of the range.

I have multiple tables on a sheet with different dimensions. I want to go through column "A", and colour the entire row of the table (and not outside the table).

The range is dynamic i.e. the columns might vary.

(https://www.dropbox.com/s/y9is3xerqps0q7e/example.JPG?dl=0) - image link

How do I make the range dynamic?

The answers I got online were confusing. Conditional formatting isn't an option since I am losing other formatting i.e. borders around tables etc. (not shown in the image) when I apply it.

```vb
Sub highlight()
    
    Dim LastRow as Long
    
    Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
    Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count. "A'").End(xlUp).Row
    
    For n= LastRow to1 Step -1
        If sht.Cells(n, "A").Value = "series3" Then sht.Range(?????).Interior.ColorIndex = 29
    
        'Continues like this for series4, series5 and so on
    
    Next n

End Sub
```

I am stumped when it comes to what goes inside Range().

Comment: Are these just ranges or ranges converted into excel tables? Or ranges that have just been given names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a last column variable. Currently, this calculates the last column (`LC`) at the row level before highlighting. If you have a list of tables (or named ranges), you could just loop through the table objects (or array of named ranges) and calculate the last column at the header level of each table.

I'm not sure if there is a reason you are looping backwards, but that has been undone here just for the example. If your only operation is to highlight, it makes no difference here.

```
Sub Dynamic_HL()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

Dim LR As Long, LC As Long, i As Long

LR = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 to LR
    If ws.Range("A" & i) = "series3" Then
        LC = ws.Cells(i, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        ws.Range(ws.Cells(i, 1), ws.Cells(i, LC)).Interior.ColorIndex = 29
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I ran this code but it highlighted the same number of columns in the second table as it did in the first i.e referring to the image attached, it missed the series criteria10 and onwards for the second table.

Comment: Updated to calculate the column length of each row individually before highlighting

Comment: Hey, will it work if there are hidden cells between the tables as well? Doesn't seem t0 be working in this case :/. just want to make sure I cover all bases, sorry

Comment: Questions like these you should test for yourself :)

Comment: I did, hence the doubt, sorry :/. To give some context, I am hiding/unhiding a bunch of charts through a macro. So the sheets I see on a page have a lot of hidden rows between them. When I applied this code for the sample data (from the image), it worked though. Not sure why this is happening.

Comment: Notice the code is calling for specific rows. Row 5 is still row 5 regardless of if it’s hidden or not - thus, why it works